# How to add a dynamic cart link to the user menu?

Tags: routes, commerce

Commerce already defines two menu items in the Navigation menu:

- Shopping cart - 'cart' - enabled by default, static
- Shopping cart - 'cart/my' - disabled by default, dynamic

'cart/my' uses a custom title callback, 'commerce_cart_menu_item_title' that builds a dynamic menu link in the form: Shopping cart (2 items)

If I want to add a new menu item for the shopping cart to the User Menu, what's the proper way to do this? Do I first need to duplicate a menu item, then override the duplicate?

Ideally, I would be able to set my own title callback so that I can optionally build a dynamic menu in any format I choose.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new menu programatically through [menu hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), and a great source for sample code and explanation is the menu_example portion of the [Examples Module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)

For example

```
function mymodule_menu() {
     $items['cart/new_menu_item'] = array(
    'title' => 'Shopping cart (# items)',
    'title callback' => 'mymodule_new_menu_item_title',
    'title arguments' => array(TRUE),
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_new_menu_item_redirect',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM, 
  );
  return $items;
}
```